# function that changes a uint variable of days give error - solidity

Tags: function, solidity

I have a uint variable that contains days, through a function I wish I could have the ability to change but it gives me this error when I compile the code:

```
unexpected "days" after "time"
```

this is my code:

```
 uint public  cliff = 0 days;

 function changeCliff(uint time) public onlyOwner {
    cliff = time days;
}
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These suffixes cannot be applied to variables. For example, if you want to interpret a function parameter in days, you can in the following way:
>
> ```
> function f(uint start, uint daysAfter) public {
>     if (block.timestamp >= start + daysAfter * 1 days) {
>       // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Source: [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units)

So applied to your code:

```
cliff = time * 1 days;
```